# Device Admin Lock Screen feature: Swipe vs. None

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

How do i differentiate between Screen Lock setting that is set to `NONE` from that which is set to `SWIPE`?

I do not see the `onReceive()` getting called in my custom broadcast receiver that extends `DeviceAdminReceiver` when i switch back and forth between these two options.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,